# How to locate a Chrome tab from its process PID?

Tags: process, chrome

I opened many Chrome tabs for webpages.

Each tab has its own PID, e.g.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
t         3900  1.9  6.3 5718440 508660 ?      Sl   Jun08 188:31 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=3862.0.1604359319 --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=1,12,42 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x2a42 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-version
```

I wonder how to find out which tab from many opened tabs corresponds to a given PID?

Answer (score 31):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up Chrome's task manager. Locate the line corresponding to the PID you want (click on the “Process ID” column header to sort by PID). Double-click the line to bring the tab to the foreground.

Comment: I think it is good to put the _chrome_ key in search bar of system activity window. Also the tab **did not** show in my system activity when I click. I've tested all chromium processes. (I use chromium of course)

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by “chrome key”? What do you mean by “system activity”? In the task manager, double clicking on a line brings up the corresponding tab. This works both in Chromium and Chrome.

Comment: I mean it's good to search `chrome` in chrome activity window. then the other processes will hide.

Comment: Note that Chrome v.71 on macOS no longer has this shortcut set; its Task Manager can be found under the Window menu, grouped with Downloads and Extensions. Or just search "task manager" (or substring) in its Help menu.

Comment: I wish there was a programmatic way to do this?

Comment: @SayanDey Looks like [you can list processes from an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes/).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks, I was looking for some bash script, I need to have control over an opened chrome tab via bash script

Comment: On my linux machine the PIDs listed by `ps -C chromium-browser` are all different to the PIDs listed in the task manager. Why?

Comment: @Ben Processes have several things that could be considered names (search the site, I'm sure this has been answered before). Presumably your task manager and `ps -C` don't use the same.

Comment: I'm talking about the numeric PID's (which I thought was an unambiguous process identifier); there is no overlap between the PID numbers reported by task manager and those reported by `ps`. Which makes it very difficult to work out how they match up. Perhaps this is a security feature? Is chromium-browser using it's own internal process numbering system?

Comment: @Ben Linux has PID namespaces, but unless you're doing something unusual, you wouldn't have different PID namespaces on a desktop machine. It's possible (although it would admittedly be usual) that `ps -C chromium-browser` displays a different set of processes than filtering for `chromium-browser` in some GUI task manager. Another possibility is that the task manager may be displaying kernel threads and not just processes.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' OK I figured out the problem; I forgot that I was running chromium-browser under firejail which creates a new PID namespace. `firejail --join=<PID>` gets me a shell in the same namespace as chromium-browser where I can check the processes.

Answer (score 10):

in chromium address bar type: about:memory. It will show process ID and memory consumption of each tab:

[image]

Comment: That gives you the tab title, but is there a way to get to the actual tab?

Comment: No, It does not show the tab when you click on it in my chromium.